# Использование слов "усидчивость" и "настойчивость"

Tags: значение-слов

Человек не доделал что-то до конца.
Какое слово лучше для его характеристики: ему не хватило усидчивости или настойчивости?

Comment: Это разные качества. Мы не знаем, какого из них ему не хватило. Опишите ситуацию подробней.

Comment: Если требовалось сидеть - усидчивости, если стоять - настойчивости (шутка)

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от конкретной ситуации.

**Человек решил написать книгу**: нашел интересную тему,  загорелся идеей, но от замысла до воплощения путь не близкий.

Нужно поработать со многими источниками, а здесь нужны **усидчивость и терпение.** Нужно попасть в архивы (а не везде пускают), встретиться со многими людьми (а это не так просто). Чтобы решить все эти постоянно возникающие проблемы,   требовалось  проявить упорство и  **настойчивость**.

Но кропотливая работа утомила, препятствия охладили пыл – вот и нет книги. Не хватило у автора **ни усидчивости, ни настойчивости**.

УСИДЧИВЫЙ,  1. Способный усердно, длительно заниматься тем, что требует сидячей работы. 2. Разг. Требующий терпения, кропотливой сидячей работы.

НАСТОЙЧИВЫЙ, Решительно, упорно добивающийся своей цели.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста, как правильно прокомментировали выше. Усидчивость это именно свойство делать сидячую работу не отвлекаясь. Пассивное слово, так сказать. Грызть гранит науки, или зубрить - тут нужна усидчивость. А если работа предполагает активные действия - тогда нужна настойчивость. "Кто ищет, тот всегда найдет" и т.п.

Answer (score -1):

Работа не доведена до конца, и не достало ли настойчивости или усидчивости — не имеет значения: не эти качества определяют или, если определяют, то в равных долях (**Н. — умение двигаться строго выбранным курсом, а У. — умение не отвлекаться на другое, что одно и то же**) успех в делах и их завершение в срок. Если речь идёт не о нотации гимназисту, часто формального и типового — норовит вскочить неусидчивый, отвлекается не настойчивый, — то следует использовать категорию осознания человеком важности и неотложности взятого на себя дела — ответственность.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте ваш ответ более понятным и конкретным.